# Vue.js 3 prevent watcher from triggering itself

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Is there any way to prevent a watcher from triggering itself?

Example:

```js
const page = ref(1);
const pageCount = 10;

// Will trigger twice when page.value is 11 or higher
watch(page, () => {
    page.value = Math.min(page.value, pageCount);
});
```

I would like to update page without triggering the same watcher again. In this simple example a second trigger wouldn't be an issue but I've encountered a few situations where the side effects of the watcher would cause issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `watchEffect` instead of `watch` :

```js
const page = ref(1);
const pageCount = 10;
 
watchEffect(()=> {
    page.value = Math.min(page.value, pageCount);
});
```